# Twitter Bootstrap Tabs double click issue // Anchor Tag within tab content Issue

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, anchor, scrollspy

**Intro:**
This html page has 3 sections. Bootstrap Tabs as images(Top) when clicked should scroll to the tabbed content. Within each tabs tabbed content you have a (middle) section with price ranges which will filter the product blocks below (Bottom).

**Issue #1** 
When setting anchor tags, clicking the tab it should scroll down to the tabbed content. Problem: When clicking on tabs the anchor tag scroll only works on the first tab.

**Issue #2**
When Double clicking the Tabs the tabbed content disappears. Bug?

Code: http://www.bootply.com/jasonethedesigner/YbdSPgyAb5#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for Issue #2 :
it's because `display: none` of second and third tabs!
you can create a div in top of tabs with `display: block` and set that for target of scroll after click the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

- I don't know why you are removing active class from your tab panes
  and trying to add to the current one, Bootstrap is doing it
  automatically.
- **Issue #1:** If you want to do that anyway you have to change your `index`
  variable value, because it's always returning 0, that's the reason your tab panes disappear on second click, you have to use
  `index()` function on the parent (`li` element):

```
var index = jQuery(this).parent().index() - 1;
```

- **Issue #2:** It should scroll but it doesn't because when you click on the 2nd or 3rd tab they have `display: none` so browser doesn't know where to scroll, you can use this in your click event:

```
var target = jQuery($(this).attr('href'));
setTimeout(function() {
  jQuery('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: jQuery(target).offset().top
  }, 'slow');
}, 50);
```

### [BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/kXG7kRUXQt)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Per your response to issue one, I had a conflict with one of the scripts being used on this clients site (Magento) this helped as a workaround (quick fix).

Comment: Ah ok, no problem ;)

Comment: I cant believe I missed that....   uugh. Thank you. Its been a hectic week in the retail world. Let me give this a shot.